# Erro tentando desenhar grafico: "comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho uma função:

```
my_gamma = function(x)
{
    f = function(t){t^(x-1) * exp(-t)}
    integrate(f, 0, Inf)
}
```

Estou tentando desenhar o seu gráfico com `ggplot2`:

```
plot = ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0.01, 10)), aes(x=x))
(plot + stat_function(fun = my_gamma))
```

Mas está me dando o erro:

```
Warning messages:
1: In t^(x - 1) :
  comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
2: In t^(x - 1) * exp(-t) :
  comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
3: Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

O que estou a fazer de errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O principal problema é que a função não está vetorizada.
O segundo problema é que `integrate` retorna uma *lista*, mas `stat_function` precisa de um vetor de números.

Então, primeiro corrige-se a função.

```
my_gamma <- function(x){
  f <- function(t){t^(x - 1) * exp(-t)}
  integrate(f, 0, Inf)$value
}
```

Agora vetoriza-se e testa-se a forma vetorizada.

```
myGamma <- Vectorize(my_gamma)
myGamma(seq(0.1, 10, length.out = 20))
# [1] 9.513504e+00 1.442807e+00 9.356940e-01 9.021743e-01 1.092452e+00
# [6] 1.551187e+00 2.488839e+00 4.409250e+00 8.490126e+00 1.756589e+01
#[11] 3.871311e+01 9.026446e+01 2.214427e+02 5.690236e+02 1.525743e+03
#[16] 4.255200e+03 1.230969e+04 3.684868e+04 1.139016e+05 3.628800e+05
```

Finalmente, o gráfico. Incluí um argumento `length.out` em `seq`.

```
plot <- ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0.01, 10, length.out = 20)), aes(x=x))
plot + stat_function(fun = myGamma)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]